# Why are Leiningen download dependencies in ~/.m2/repository directory?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have created a new project using Leiningen. When I added a new dependency and ran `lein deps`, the lein downloaded the dependencies in `~/.m2/repository` directory.

Shouldn't the project specific dependencies be downloaded in a directory that is local to the project and not into the global directory like `~/.m2/repository`.

For example - While I used `npm`, it gave me 2 options, i.e., to download the dependency locally (in project's `node_modules` directory) or globally.

Comment: `lein` uses maven for dependency resolution and `~/.m2/repository` is the default location of the local maven repo.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike npm, lein uses maven and maven dependencies are stored in a globally shared directory, defaulting to `~/.m2/repository`.

Answer (score 0):

As previous pointed `lein` uses `maven` and maven's "local repository" is by default in the `${user.home}/.m2/repository` folder.

You can control/change this from your maven (user) settings file `${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml` or (global) settings file `${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml` by defining the entry:

```
<localRepository>${user.home}/.m2/repository</localRepository>
```

for more details check: [maven settings reference](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html)